# cargar en otro div checkbox seleccionados - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**tengo dos botones uno se llama "seleccionar" y el otro se llama "seleccionados" y al darle clic en seleccionar me carga "3 div" cada uno contiene un checkbox y lo que necesito es que al seleccionar algun checkbox este me aparezca tambien con el div en "seleccionados" cuando le de clic al boton de seleccionados, he intentado de varias formas pero no he logrado que funcione, envió mi código .**

lo que necesito: es que al seleccionar algun de los 3 checks que tengo estos tambien aparezcan cuando vaya al div de "seleccionados"

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function Pruebas3() {

  const [value2, setValue2] = useState("");

  const handlerOnClick = (e) => {
    setValue2(e.target.value)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
        <div className="form-check">

        <input type="button" name="boton1" value="seleccionar"         
            onClick={handlerOnClick}
        /> 
        
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <input type="button" name="boton1" value="seleccionados"  onClick={handlerOnClick}
          /> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-sm-7">
        {value2 === "seleccionar" && (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">

        <div name="check1" >Div1<input type="checkbox" name="check_1" /></div>
        <div name="check2" >Div2<input type="checkbox" name="check_2"/></div>
        <div name="check3" >Div3<input type="checkbox" name="check_3"/></div>

            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-7">
        {value2 === "seleccionados" && (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h1>CHECK seleccionados</h1>
              {
                  if(check_1 == true){
                    <div name="check1" >Div1<input type="checkbox" name="check_1" /></div>
                  }else if (check_2 == true){
                    <div name="check2" >Div2<input type="checkbox" name="check_2" /></div> 
                  }else if (check_3 == true){
                    <div name="check3" >Div3<input type="checkbox" name="check_3" /></div> 
                  }
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas3
```

Comment: hola Geovany, tu pregunta necesita un poco de redacción ya que no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres lograr

Comment: ya agregue algo mas puntual de lo que necesito

Comment: ok, ya te estoy haciendo una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si tu objetivo es añadir los seleccionados infinatemnete seria hacer un estado para seleccionados, si la relacion es que desaparezca de selccionados si deselecciono el de arriba debes manejar un unico estado con un atributo active para que no dupliques datos

aqui hay un ejemplo

[ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-fast-ut18u7?file=/src/App.js:178-186)

Comment: ya revise el ejemplo pero le falta varias cosas, la primera cuando selecciono un div "checkbox" en seleccionar debe aparecer el mismo si el div donde esta el checkbox tiene algunos elementos de igual forma debe aparecer en seleccionados, y lo segundo el div de seleccionados solo debe aparecer cuando le doy clic en el boton de seleccionados como lo tengo en el ejemplo.